# Passing data to new form while it's opening

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VB.net and passing data from one form to another while it is opening to load data to a header on the second form. The data that is passed is a JobID key that is used in an SQL statment that will call the data from a database that is then used to populate the static header on form 2.

So here is the problem, I can transfer the data, however, the header will not populate unless I have a msgbox in the code right before I fill the dataset. Here is the code, I'd love to get this to work without the msgbox.

Form1

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class assemblyForm
   Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
   Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
   Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
   Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
   Dim ds As New DataSet, ds2 As New DataSet, ds3 As New DataSet
   Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter, da2 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter, da3 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
   Dim run As Integer, pcr As Integer, JobId2 As Integer, jobNum As Integer

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try
        'Open DB connection
        dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\crabara\Desktop\Project Alpha 3\MDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        dbConnect.Open()

        'Autopopulate PartNo. textbox
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PartNumber FROM PCR_INFO", dbConnect)

        da.Fill(ds, "list")

        Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("PartNumber").ToString())
        Next

        txtPart.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txtPart.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
        txtPart.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Line + "Main Database Not Found" + Line + "Check form_AccessMaintenance source code" + Line + "Database Path", "Critical Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'Increment the Run
    dbInsert.CommandText = "UPDATE PART_LIST SET Run = Run + 1 WHERE PartNumber='" & txtPart.Text & "'"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Gather Run from PART_LIST DB, put into variable
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Run FROM PART_LIST WHERE PartNumber ='" & txtPart.Text & "'", dbConnect)

    da.Fill(ds, "Run")

    run = CInt(ds.Tables("Run").Rows(0).Item(0))

    'Gather PCR from PCR_INFO DB, put into variable

    da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PCRNumber FROM PCR_INFO WHERE PartNumber ='" & txtPart.Text & "'", dbConnect)

    da2.Fill(ds2, "PCRNumber")

    pcr = CInt(ds2.Tables("PCRNumber").Rows(0).Item(0))



    'Set parameters for fields
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "PartNumber"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("PartNumber").Value = txtPart.Text
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "PCRNumber"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("PCRNumber").Value = pcr
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Run"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Run").Value = run
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "JobNo"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("JobNo").Value = txtJobNo.Text



    'Add Values into Assembly DB
    dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Assembly(PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run,JobNo) VALUES(txtPart.Text,pcr,run,txtJobNo.Text);"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Job has been successfully submitted" + Line + txtPart.Text)


    'Gather JobID from new job

    da3 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT JobID FROM Assembly WHERE PartNumber ='" & txtPart.Text & "' AND JobNo ='" & txtJobNo.Text & "'", dbConnect)

    da3.Fill(ds3, "JobID")

    JobId2 = CInt(ds3.Tables("JobID").Rows(0).Item(0))

    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "JobID"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("JobID").Value = JobId2


    'Add Values into Vinyl DB
    dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO    Molding(PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run,JobNo,JobID)   VALUES(txtPart.Text,pcr,run,txtJobNo.Text,JobId2);"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Loads the newly created jobid into the vinyl form
    Dim anotherForm As Vinyl
    anotherForm = New Vinyl(JobId2)
    anotherForm.Show()


End Sub
```

Form 2

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Public Class Vinyl

Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
Dim ds As New DataSet, ds2 As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter, da2 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim PartNumber As String, PartDescription As String
Dim PCR As Integer, run As Integer, jobnumber As Integer
Dim Pdescription As String

' Bring data from previous form and load the header
Public Sub New(ByVal JobNum As Integer)
    MyBase.New()
    InitializeComponent()

    jobnumber = JobNum

End Sub




Private Sub Vinyl_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\crabara\Desktop\Project Alpha 3\MDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    dbConnect.Open()


    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run FROM Molding WHERE JobID ='" & jobnumber & "'", dbConnect)
    'Have to have a msgbox right here in order for this cod
    'MsgBox(jobnumber)
    da.Fill(ds, "Molding")


    PartNumber = CStr(ds.Tables("Molding").Rows(0).Item(0))
    PCR = CInt(ds.Tables("Molding").Rows(0).Item(1))
    run = CInt(ds.Tables("Molding").Rows(0).Item(2))

    lblPart.Text = PartNumber
    lblPCR.Text = CStr(PCR)
    lblRun.Text = CStr(run)

    da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PartDescription FROM PART_LIST WHERE PartNumber ='" & PartNumber & "'", dbConnect)
    ' MsgBox(PartNumber)
    da2.Fill(ds2, "PartDescription")

    Pdescription = CStr((ds2.Tables("PartDescription").Rows(0).Item(0)))

    lblPartDescription.Text = CStr(Pdescription)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Most of the stuff in your `Form2.New(..)` method should be in your `Form_Load` instead.  Everything after you save the `jobnumber`.

Comment: No that doesn't work, I just tried it again. I assume you mean everything from dbconnect and down. My understanding is the the Form_load will take load before the public sub

Comment: @Crabara No, the constructor runs first.  The load event comes after, and it could be that some of your components need to go through that windows initialization stage.  The jubnumber value should be set in the constructor and try moving everything else into the OnLoad override method (the load event essentially).

Comment: @LarsTech, ok I've done that. Take a look at the code I've edited to see if that is exactly what you mean. That doesn't work.

Comment: Weird. Does putting the MessageBox in the Form_Load still work?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Yes it does. Putting the MessageBox in the Form_Load makes it work. Weird I know I've been banging my head over this for two days now.

Comment: `That doesn't work` doesn't tell us anything.  Errors?  You have a debugger, use it.  Step through the code and examine the values as it gets processed.

Comment: @LarsTech I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll" I assume this is because the jobnumber variable is empty so when it searches the dataset there is nothing there at row(0) and column(0). I've tried stepping into each line of code and if I do that, it works. So I'm trying to use the debugger but it isn't actually giving me a bug.

Comment: It obviously has something to do with the activation/display sequencing and timing, and debug can mess that up.  Put `Debug.Print` statements in to trace it, then run it without stepping in debug.

Comment: In the first line of the load event, write `Debug.WriteLine("JobNum = " & jobnumber.ToString)`.  Run the program and look at the output in the Immediate Window (Debug - Windows - Immediate menus).

Comment: Arlighty I've done that, this is the information I get back in the immediate window. Not really new information to me. "JobNum = 137
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: @Crabara Your INSERT query is still full of problems.  I have a hard time believing your aren't getting errors from that `dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()` call.  You aren't passing any parameters and the ones you have are local variables.

Comment: How is your "header" connected to any of this?  I don't see any controls other than the labels referenced.  Are they the headers?

Comment: @LarsTech I believe I did set parameters, I just haven't included it in my code I've shown. Anyways, I've edited it to show you the whole code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, When I said "Headers" I was just referencing the fact that it was static, but essentially it is just labels. Put into a couple of panels, I'm an intern doing this with zero guidance, so this is all new to me and fairly advanced for my skill level. So please have mercy with me lol

Comment: While running the code with debug print statements I get this "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll" I get this right after " da.Fill(ds, "Molding")" On form 2

Comment: Does "right after" mean that it occurs while executing that line?  Or is it when executing the next line (`PartNumber = ...`)?

Comment: It is at that line, I believe.

Comment: It has to be at that line, because it I put a msgbox after that line it won't work. The msgbox has to be before that line.

Comment: @RBarryYoung,I appreciate the help, i cannot figure this out. Looks like I'll figure out a way to incorporate a messagebox or a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out, I just needed to close the dbconnection on form1 after the dbinsert.executenonquery. My hunch is that the db never lost focus, so the program couldn't grab the jobnumber value because it was still open and being written to. When the messagebox was placed there it took focus from the db. so here is the updated code.

```
 Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class assemblyForm
   Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
   Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
   Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.enter code here`
   Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
   Dim ds As New DataSet, ds2 As New DataSet, ds3 As New DataSet
   Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter, da2 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter, da3 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
   Dim run As Integer, pcr As Integer, JobId2 As Integer, jobNum As Integer

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try
        'Open DB connection
        dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\crabara\Desktop\Project Alpha 3\MDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        dbConnect.Open()

        'Autopopulate PartNo. textbox
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PartNumber FROM PCR_INFO", dbConnect)

        da.Fill(ds, "list")

        Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("PartNumber").ToString())
        Next

        txtPart.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txtPart.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
        txtPart.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Line + "Main Database Not Found" + Line + "Check form_AccessMaintenance source code" + Line + "Database Path", "Critical Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'Increment the Run
    dbInsert.CommandText = "UPDATE PART_LIST SET Run = Run + 1 WHERE PartNumber='" & txtPart.Text & "'"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Gather Run from PART_LIST DB, put into variable
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Run FROM PART_LIST WHERE PartNumber ='" & txtPart.Text & "'", dbConnect)

    da.Fill(ds, "Run")

    run = CInt(ds.Tables("Run").Rows(0).Item(0))

    'Gather PCR from PCR_INFO DB, put into variable

    da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PCRNumber FROM PCR_INFO WHERE PartNumber ='" & txtPart.Text & "'", dbConnect)

    da2.Fill(ds2, "PCRNumber")

    pcr = CInt(ds2.Tables("PCRNumber").Rows(0).Item(0))



    'Set parameters for fields
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "PartNumber"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("PartNumber").Value = txtPart.Text
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "PCRNumber"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("PCRNumber").Value = pcr
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Run"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Run").Value = run
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "JobNo"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("JobNo").Value = txtJobNo.Text



    'Add Values into Assembly DB
    dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Assembly(PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run,JobNo) VALUES(txtPart.Text,pcr,run,txtJobNo.Text);"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Job has been successfully submitted" + Line + txtPart.Text)


    'Gather JobID from new job

    da3 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT JobID FROM Assembly WHERE PartNumber ='" & txtPart.Text & "' AND JobNo ='" & txtJobNo.Text & "'", dbConnect)

    da3.Fill(ds3, "JobID")

    JobId2 = CInt(ds3.Tables("JobID").Rows(0).Item(0))

    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "JobID"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("JobID").Value = JobId2


    'Add Values into Vinyl DB
    dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO    Molding(PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run,JobNo,JobID)   VALUES(txtPart.Text,pcr,run,txtJobNo.Text,JobId2);"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbconnect.Close()

    'Loads the newly created jobid into the vinyl form
    Dim anotherForm As Vinyl
    anotherForm = New Vinyl(JobId2)
    anotherForm.Show()


End Sub
```